# VB 2008 Possible to have a database inside the .exe file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm currently making a personal account manager program and right now I've achieved creating one but there is a visible .accdb file along with the .exe itself. And it is not very safe since the .accdb can just be opened.

Is there anyway to achieve this without having a visible database? Or any secure way in achieving this would be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend considering an encrypted/password-protected database.  If you don't want to [do that](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Encrypt-a-database-by-using-a-database-password-fe1cc5fe-f9a5-4784-b090-fdb2673457ab) with access, you may want to consider another engine such as SQLite.

Comment: [Security Considerations and Guidance for Access 2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb421308(v=office.12).aspx).  No, you cannot embed a ReadWrite database file inside the EXE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact Edition supports encryption.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg592949(v=sql.110).aspx

And no, you aren't going to be able to embed it in the .exe unless you come up with a tremendously complex scheme of recompiling the .exe every time the database changes.

You could set the hidden attribute on the database file, though, to try to obscure it.  It just depends on whether your goal is to stop competent hackers (which it won't do) or just to stop a user from accidently deleting or renaming it (which it will do).  A hidden, encrypted, file would do both.